# How to check magento users are logged in or not?

Tags: magento-1.9, session, permissions, user-roles

I have 3 Magento users with certain roles and access permission in
backend end, i want to know that how many users where logged in,
depends up on the logged In users user specific pop up will appear,
Suppose i have 3 users called

- 1.Don1
- 2.Don2
- 3.Don3

I want to know that who is currently logged in and depends upon the user role i need to show a popup magento, is there any method to find out the logged in users.

Comment: By magento users, do you mean magento admin panel users, or, frontend  customers?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about Admin users when you mention user role

This code should tell you the admins role

```
$admin_user_session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$adminuserId = $admin_user_session->getUser()->getUserID();
$role = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($adminuserId)->getRole()->getData();
```

I'd wrap it in an IF to make sure they're logged in before firing it, something like

```
if($admin_user_session){
    switch ($role) {
        case 'Don1':
            // Do something for Don 1
            break;
        case 'Don2':
            // Do something for Don 2
            break;
        case 'Don3':
            // Do something for Don 3
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Error Call to a member function getUserId()

Comment: Sorry, I've just edited my answer. Try getUserID (Capital I and D)

Comment: Alternatively you can try getId, or perhaps getID - Sorry, I don't have Magento infront of me so I'm unable to check properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cursession = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$userId = $cursession->getUser()->getUserId();
$role = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($userId)->getRole()->getData();
```

You can get role regarding data in the **$role** array. By using that, You can show your desired message.

Answer (score 0):

**To get logged in user in admin-end.**

```
    $admin = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
    if ($admin->getId()){
        echo $admin->getUsername();
    }
```

**To get logged in user role**

```
$role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($admin->getId())->getRole()->getData();
```

**To get logged in user in front-end.**

```
$customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
     $customerData = $customerSession->getCustomer();
     echo $customerData->getId();
 }
```